How do I get a per pixel linear regression analysis of a raster stack across time when time is only saved as the tiff file name?
I have single band rasters of data values averaged per year from 1986-2023. I would like to run a trend anlysis that gives me the linear regressions of each pixel across the years. I am not sure where to start but I can forsee the problem that if I run a function on the raster stack the year data is lost as it is only saved in the image file name and doesn't appear in the stack dataframe.
I have so far attempted to run
fun <- function (x) { if (is.na(x[ 1 ]))   
  else {cochrane.orcutt(lm(x[ 1 :a] ~ x[( 1 +a):(a+b)]))$coefficients[ 2 ] }}
slope <- calc(stack, fun)


You can create a multiband image containing the single-band rasters using c and perform a linear regression with regress, using a simple vector of the years as the predictive variable. Here is the code with a short example.
library(terra)

im1 <- c(rast(matrix(1:9, nrow = 3)),
  rast(matrix(2:10, nrow = 3)),
  rast(matrix(3:11, nrow = 3)))

years <- 2000:2002

lreg <- regress(y = im1, x = years, formula = y~x)

